# What is the counterpart for SUM() in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

In `SQL Server` you can do sum(field1) to get the sum of all fields that match the groupby clause.
But I need to have the fields subtracted, not summed.
Is there something like subtract(field1) that I can use in stead of sum(field1) ?

For example, table1 has this content :

```
name field1  
A 1  
A 2  
B 4
```

Query:

```
select name, sum(field1), subtract(field1)  
from table1  
group by name
```

would give me:

```
A 3 -1  
B 4 4
```

I hope my question is clear.

EDIT :

there is also a sortfield that i can use.
This makes sure that values 1 and 2 will always lead to -1 an not to 1.

What I need is all values for A subtracted, in my example 1 - 2 = -1

EDIT2 :
if the A-group has values 1, 2, 3, 4 the result must be 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 = -8

Comment: subtract would translate to `SUM(-field1)` but from the example you gave that wouldn't give you the results you want. You want `+X1-X2-X3` which is not the reverse of sum, being `+X1+X2+X3`.

Comment: You would have to have a column that indicates an order because 2-1 is not 1-2

Comment: You must elaborate on how this function should work. What if the A-group had the following values: 1, 2, 3, 4, what should the end result be, and why?

Comment: if A group has values 1, 2, 3, 4 the result must be 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 = -8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have some column to indicate order, to select first element per group, you could use windowed functions to calculate your `substract`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name CHAR(1), field1 INT);
INSERT INTO tab(name, field1) VALUES ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 4);

SELECT DISTINCT 
   name
   ,[sum]       = SUM(field1) OVER (PARTITION BY name)
   ,[substract] = SUM(-field1) OVER (PARTITION BY name) 
                  + 2*FIRST_VALUE(field1) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ID)
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/WMM92764)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔══════╦═════╦═══════════╗
║ name ║ sum ║ substract ║
╠══════╬═════╬═══════════╣
║ A    ║   3 ║        -1 ║
║ B    ║   4 ║         4 ║
╚══════╩═════╩═══════════╝
```

Warning:

`FIRST_VALUE` is available from `SQL Server 2012+`

Answer (score 2):

So you want to subtract the sum of the second to last from the first value?

You need a column to indicate the order. If you don't have a logical column  like a `datetime` column you could use the primary-key.

Here's an example which uses common table expression(CTE's) and the `ROW_NUMBER`-function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Field1,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By name ORDER BY Id)
    FROM dbo.Table1
), MinValues AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Field1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
)
, OtherValues AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Field1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN > 1
)
SELECT mv.Name, 
       MIN(mv.Field1) - COALESCE(SUM(ov.Field1), 0) AS Subtract
FROM MinValues mv LEFT OUTER JOIN  OtherValues ov 
    ON mv.Name = ov.Name
GROUP BY mv.Name
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/ZYWF59906)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
declare @t table(name char(1), field1  int)
insert into @t
select 'A', 1 union all  
select 'A', 2  union all
select 'B', 4



select name, sum(field1) as addition,
             sum(case when sno=1 then field1 else -field1 end) as subtraction from 
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by name order by (select 1)) as sno from @t 
) as t2 group by name
```

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` is not reliable. It could return values as they are in table but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

On top of all the answers with algorithm to solve your problem, you have to keep in mind, that SUM is an aggregate on the set of data. There is no order of execution you can predict here.

That's why people are mentioning SUM (-field) - which is not really a subtract operation, it will just reverse the values and use SUM on the set of data as it really doesn't make any sense to 'subtract' on SET. Subtract would need you to define order of arguments selection to apply a binary operator on them.